# Google prevents me from logging into my Google account when the Chrome window is launched by Selenium. How can i do?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, webdriver

here is the problem :

Google prevents me from logging into my Google account when the Chrome browser is launched by Python and Selenium to scrape some data. The same with Firefox. I tried downgrading Chrome to v78 and blocked the updates but it's still the same.

How can i get past this problem ? Thank you in advance for your feedback.
(This is my first question on StackOverFlow, sorry if my question is poorly worded).

Pictures speak better than words, below two screenshots to describe the problem :

[need google account sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8pcZ.png)

[couldn't sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8Cmr.png)

Comment: That may be a security “feature” since chrome and google are the same... have you tried chromium? Also, sometimes all you need is an active session in any browser to scrape data from cli/script without launching another browser.

Comment: Thanks sadtank for your return. Yes I tried with chromium (webdriver), firefox too (geckodriver) but it didn't work. In fact I got some data from a site and I want to use it in a google form but I can't access my account. Google recognizes that it is a bot which opened the window so for security it prevents the connection.

Comment: I'd try copying Google cookies from a real browser into selenium session, instead of trying to login with Selenium. https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/support_packages/working_with_cookies/